# when i insert multiple rows using multiple insert statements it is raising an error but when i use single rows then its good whatwrong

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
       (EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
        ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
        JOB VARCHAR2(9),
        MGR NUMBER(4),
        HIREDATE DATE,
        SAL NUMBER(7,2),
        COMM NUMBER(7,2),
       DEPTNO NUMBER(2))
```

SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,'17-DEC-80',800,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-FEB-81',1600,300,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-FEB-81',1250,500,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,'2-APR-81',2975,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
      (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,'28-SEP-81',1250,1400,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,'1-MAY-81',2850,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,'9-JUN-81',2450,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,'09-DEC-82',3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,'17-NOV-81',5000,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,'8-SEP-81',1500,0,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,'12-JAN-83',1100,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
      (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,'3-DEC-81',950,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
       (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,'3-DEC-81',3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
      (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,'23-JAN-82',1300,NULL,10);
```

SQL> /
        (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,'17-DEC-80',800,NULL,20);                  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00911: invalid character 
plz help me

Comment: Is the above the code that is causing the error or the code that is working ? you said you tried 2 things and one work

Answer (score 2):

When you run a SQL statement in SQL*Plus, which is what it looks like you're using, the editor expects 1 statement. When you use the editor to create multiple insert statements as you have done, it considers them as one statement, which they're clearly not.

You have multiple options:

1. wrap the insert statements up in a begin/end and run it as a pl/sql
   block
2. put the insert statements into a text file (eg. ins_stmts.sql) and
   then call that file as a script (eg. @ins_stmts.sql)
3. rewrite the insert statements as a single insert statement as
   select, by using the dual table to turn them into rows, union all'd
   together, eg:

   ```
   insert into emp (empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno)
   select 7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_date('17-DEC-1980', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),800,NULL,20 from dual union all
   select 7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('20-FEB-1981', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),1600,300,30 union all
   ...
   ```

P.s. it is good practice to list the columns you're inserting into after the tablename.

Also, when you're inserting into a column that is of DATE (or TIMESTAMP) datatype, you should do the conversion from your string to the date explicitly using `to_date()` (or `to_timestamp()` for TIMESTAMPs), rather than relying on the default nls_date_format settings as you are currently doing. Also, years have 4 digits, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Treat it as a script.  That is, issue the following command from SQL*Plus:

```
 start afiedt.buf
```